# Limiting variable names in sql scripts

Tags: sql, oracle

In bash scripts, just as braces {} can be used to limit names of variables like

```
echo "${HOURS}h ${MINUTES}m ${SECONDS}s"
```

is there a way to unambiguously specify variable names in SQL scripts? I am using Oracle SQL and looking for something like below.

```
define user=&1
spool /some/directory/&{user}_script.log
```

If I use `/some/directory/&user_script.log` then SQL assumes `user_script` as the variable name and waits for input. Instead I want it to substitute the value of the variable `user` and proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitution variables [can be terminated with a period](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458), so you can do:

```
define user=&1
spool /some/directory/&user._script.log
```

The first period will mean only `&user` is seen as the variable, not `&user_script`.

Comment: got it @Alex..i was wrong and so i deleted my answer.